# create pandas column based on condition on row values and other column grouped

Tags: pandas

I have this dataframe and trying to find the time gap between first hire and either one terminated or shift change happened earlier  when dates exists or null if conditions be true  calculate for each Employee ID

Condition 1 : first hire happened at Q4

Condition 2 : if first hire happened after 2021 and the result appear at the TimeGap column .

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Employee No': [102, 103, 102, 102, 101, 103, 101, 105, 106, 102, 107, 108, 109, 109, 109, 109], 'Event date': ['2020-10-12', '2021-11-02', '2022-01-01', '2021-12-12', '2021-12-03', '2021-11-05', '2021-12-04', '2022-02-26', '2022-02-26', '2022-03-29', '2021-05-04', '2022-04-04', '2022-03-03', '2021-12-29', '2022-04-01', '2022-01-10'], 'EventDescription': ['First Hire', 'First Hire', 'Terminated', 'Shift Change', 'First Hire', 'Terminated', 'Terminated', 'First Hire', 'First Hire', 'Second Hire', 'First Hire', 'First Hire', 'Terminated', 'First Hire', 'Second Hire', 'Shift Change'], 'Quarter': ['Q4', 'Q4', 'Q1', 'Q4', 'Q4', 'Q4', 'Q4', 'Q1', 'Q1', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q2', 'Q1', 'Q4', 'Q2', 'Q1']})

    Employee No  Event date EventDescription Quarter
0           102  2020-10-12       First Hire      Q4
1           103  2021-11-02       First Hire      Q4
2           102  2022-01-01       Terminated      Q1
3           102  2021-12-12     Shift Change      Q4
4           101  2021-12-03       First Hire      Q4
5           103  2021-11-05       Terminated      Q4
6           101  2021-12-04       Terminated      Q4
7           105  2022-02-26       First Hire      Q1
8           106  2022-02-26       First Hire      Q1
9           102  2022-03-29      Second Hire      Q1
10          107  2021-05-04       First Hire      Q2
11          108  2022-04-04       First Hire      Q2
12          109  2022-03-03       Terminated      Q1
13          109  2021-12-29       First Hire      Q4
14          109  2022-04-01      Second Hire      Q2
15          109  2022-01-10     Shift Change      Q1
```

Result should be something like this :

| index | Employee_No | Event_date | EventDescription | Quarter | Timegap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 102 | 2020-10-12 | First Hire | Q4 | NaN |
| 1 | 103 | 2021-11-02 | First Hire | Q4 | NaN |
| 2 | 102 | 2022-01-01 | Terminated | Q1 | NaN |
| 3 | 102 | 2021-12-12 | Shift Change | Q4 | NaN |
| 4 | 101 | 2021-12-03 | First Hire | Q4 | NaN |
| 5 | 103 | 2021-11-05 | Terminated | Q4 | 3.0 |
| 6 | 101 | 2021-12-04 | Terminated | Q4 | 1.0 |
| 7 | 105 | 2022-02-26 | First Hire | Q1 | NaN |
| 8 | 106 | 2022-02-26 | First Hire | Q1 | NaN |
| 9 | 102 | 2022-03-29 | Second Hire | Q1 | NaN |
| 10 | 107 | 2021-05-04 | First Hire | Q2 | NaN |
| 11 | 108 | 2022-04-04 | First Hire | Q2 | NaN |
| 12 | 109 | 2022-03-03 | Terminated | Q1 | NaN |
| 13 | 109 | 2021-12-29 | First Hire | Q4 | NaN |
| 14 | 109 | 2022-04-01 | Second Hire | Q2 | NaN |
| 15 | 109 | 2022-01-10 | Shift Change | Q1 | 12.0 |

Comment: Hi, could you show what the expected result looks like?

Comment: Result should something like the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two dataframe representing first hire and first stop, and then merge them.

```
gap_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Employee No': [102, 103, 102, 102, 101, 103, 101, 105, 106, 102, 107, 108, 109, 109, 109, 109], 'Event date': ['2020-10-12', '2021-11-02', '2022-01-01', '2021-12-12', '2021-12-03', '2021-11-05', '2021-12-04', '2022-02-26', '2022-02-26', '2022-03-29', '2021-05-04', '2022-04-04', '2022-03-03', '2021-12-29', '2022-04-01', '2022-01-10'], 'EventDescription': [
                                'First Hire', 'First Hire', 'Terminated', 'Shift Change', 'First Hire', 'Terminated', 'Terminated', 'First Hire', 'First Hire', 'Second Hire', 'First Hire', 'First Hire', 'Terminated', 'First Hire', 'Second Hire', 'Shift Change'], 'Quarter': ['Q4', 'Q4', 'Q1', 'Q4', 'Q4', 'Q4', 'Q4', 'Q1', 'Q1', 'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q2', 'Q1', 'Q4', 'Q2', 'Q1']})

gap_df["Event date"] = pd.to_datetime(gap_df["Event date"])
gap_df = gap_df.sort_values(["Employee No", "Event date"])

q4_first_hire_df = gap_df.query("Quarter == 'Q4' and EventDescription == 'First Hire'").rename({
    "Event date": "first_hire_date"}, axis=1)
q4_first_hire_df = q4_first_hire_df[q4_first_hire_df["first_hire_date"].map(
    lambda x:x.year) >= 2021]
first_stop_df = gap_df.query("EventDescription in ('Terminated','Shift Change')").groupby(
    "Employee No")["Event date"].min().reset_index().rename({"Event date": "first_stop_date"}, axis=1)

combine_df = pd.merge(q4_first_hire_df, first_stop_df, on="Employee No")
combine_df["Timegap"] = [
    x.days for x in combine_df["first_stop_date"] - combine_df["first_hire_date"]]

pd.merge(gap_df, combine_df[["Employee No", "Timegap", 'first_stop_date']],
         left_on=["Employee No", "Event date"],
         right_on=["Employee No", "first_stop_date"],
         how="left").drop("first_stop_date", axis=1)
```